# Api platform [symfony] добавить Bearer в ui swagger

Tags: api, symfony

Полностью использовал

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/

но при аутентификации в свагер используется такой курл

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:4443/api/v1/base' \
  -H 'accept: application/ld+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: 2' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
  -d '{
  "channel": "string"
}'
```

Authorization: 2 - здесь должно быть Authorization: Bearer 2

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69801383/4601822

в \App\OpenApi\JwtDecorator::__invoke

```
        $schemas = $openApi->getComponents()->getSecuritySchemes();
        $schemas['JWT'] = new \ArrayObject([
            'type' => 'http',
            'scheme' => 'bearer',
            'bearerFormat' => 'JWT'
        ]);
```

в config/packages/api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Api'
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
    patch_formats:
        json: [ 'application/merge-patch+json' ]
    swagger:
        versions: [ 3 ]
        api_keys:
            JWT:
                name: Authorization
                type: header
```

т.е. apiKey => JWT